# Returning 410 error on specific links on Nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-410

We' ve currently changed all the structure of our website and moved it from Apache to Nginx. For many links we've set properly 301 redirects, still many pages that don't exist anymore are returning 404 errors. We've a specific list of links that we need to return 410 errors but we don't know how to do that on nginx. Can someone help us on this matter please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing as we don't know what to do in these kind of situations in nginx

Comment: It would be useful to see the nginx configuration that generates the 301 redirects and an example of a link that you would like to return 410 instead.

Comment: @RichardSmith For redirects we are simply using a plugin on Wordpress called Redirection. An example would be: http://myartguides.com/categories/art/item/2894-michael-craig-martin-in-hong-kong

Comment: @Lightbox edit your post and add config to it. No need for external (broken) links.

Comment: @AlexeyTen We're not sure we've understood...many pages that we had are gone and we don't want to have them anymore...

Answer (score 4):

A map might work well here:

```
http {

    # ...

    map $uri $gone {
        default 0;
        ~^/old-link1    1;
        ~^/another-obsolete-link    1;
        # consider an included file for these
    }

    server {
        if ($gone) {
            return 410;
        }
        # ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we  need to create an include folder where to put our list of links file? Do we need to create a custom 410 page too?

Comment: Included files are relative to the nginx folder. You could add a folder for your included files then use: `include folder/redirects.conf;` You could create a custom 410 page if you want, but I don't think it's mandatory.

Comment: We've tried but it's not working...we've added the map to nginx.conf file. Was it the right file? Any idea?

Comment: The map should be outside the server block at the http level. Can you post a sample of what you tried that didn't work?

Comment: We put it at the http level in the nginx.conf file...sorry but we don't know how much nginx work so what you mean by outside the server block?

Comment: I've added some context to illustrate the location of the map with respect to the http block. By outside the server block, I mean: `server { # the map should not be in here }`

Comment: It's what we did...we've already put it inside the http block...is the file nginx.conf the correct one?

Comment: What to use location instead of map?